# group by month for attendance sheet

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

i have a table that record daily attendance.

```
CREATE TABLE  "DAILY_ATTENDANCE" (
    "SERIAL_NO" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "EMPLOYEE_ID" NUMBER(4,0), 
    "FIRST_NAME" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "MIDDLE_NAME" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "LAST_NAME" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "ATTENDANCE_DATE" DATE, 
    "STATUS" VARCHAR2(100) DEFAULT 'PRESENT', 
    "MONTH" VARCHAR2(100), 
    "YEAR" VARCHAR2(100), 
    CONSTRAINT "DAILY_ATTENDANCE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("SERIAL_NO") ENABLE, 
    CONSTRAINT "DAILY_ATTENDANCE_UK1" UNIQUE ("EMPLOYEE_ID", "ATTENDANCE_DATE")       
    ENABLE
);

create or replace trigger "DAILY_ATTENDANCE_T5"
    BEFORE insert or update on "DAILY_ATTENDANCE"
    for each row
    begin
        :new.month:= to_char(:new.ATTENDANCE_DATE, 'month') ;
        :new.year:= to_char(:new.ATTENDANCE_DATE, 'YYYY') ;
    end;
```

How do i write a simple sql statement  that gives monthly & yearly grouping of employee id and status? status has values like present,sick leave etc.
Eg: find no of sick leaves taken by employee_id=1001 in each month of year 2015?

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below query:

```
select a.year,a.month,a.employeeId,count(*)
from
(select * from DAILY_ATTENDANCE  where status ='sickleave')a
group by a.year,a.month,a.employeeId
```